# Can't find the Google Chrome User Data Directory in Mac OSX Lion

Tags: macos, google-chrome, osx-lion

I need to increase the font in my Inspect Element window in Chrome.

I found a tutorial on how to do it: http://k20e.com/blog/2011/08/18/how-to-set-the-chrome-console-font/.

According to the [Chrome website](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory), the User Data directory should be ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default, but **I don't see "Google" under "Application Support"**.

Does anyone know where else the User Data directory could be?

My Chrome is up to date (version 23.0.1271.101). Running on OS X 10.7.4 Lion.

Comment: Are you aware that `~` means `/Users/<username>`?

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you! However, **I don't see a "Library" folder** inside my user folder.

Comment: @johnym That's because it's hidden by default on OS X 10.7 and up.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`Home/Library` is a hidden folder on recent (`10.7+`) releases of OSX.

To get to the correct folder, do this:

- Open a new Finder window
- Press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>
- Type in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`

You are now in your profile directory. Click on the directory named `User StyleSheets`, and edit `Custom.css` to your heart's content!

Comment: I had to actually click Go for this to work. Hitting Enter just beeped.

Answer (score 2):

Going to try converting @William-Jackson's comment into an answer.

Are you looking at: `/Library/Application Support`?
Or, are you looking at: `/Users/*johnym*/Library/Application Support/Google.....`?

The second one is where you should be able to find the user data directory.

Comment: Thanks! As I responded to @William-Jackson, I do not have a "Library" folder inside my user folder.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into a similar problem.  I know this is an old question, but for anyone finding it in the future, the answer to "I don't see a Library folder in my username folder" is probably "OSX hid it".  (You can see the folder is a paler blue than normal viewable directories in my second screenshot in my question, [Chrome User Data: where, aside from Library, might it be?](https://superuser.com/questions/1020652/chrome-user-data-where-aside-from-library-might-it-be))

You have to reveal hidden files to see the Library directory to get to the rest of the Chrome data you need.  I did that permanently (I think) using the directions popped up in a Google search:

> **The long way to show hidden Mac OS X files is as follows:**
>
> Open Terminal found in Finder > Applications > Utilities.
>
> In Terminal, paste the following:
>
> **defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES**
>
> Press return.
>
> Hold the 'Option/alt' key, then right click on the Finder icon in the dock and click Relaunch.

Comment: I believe the shortcut for this is Shift + Cmd + .