# Chrome User Data: where, aside from Library, might it be?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, osx-yosemite

I accidentally quit Chrome; I'd like to be sure that I can get back all the tabs that were open.  (I'm typing this from Safari).  I've read that it should be possible to get them back via Recent Tabs, but I'd like to find the Current Session/Current Tabs files and back them up elsewhere, before trying to reopen Chrome, just in case.

The official website says the path for OSX is

> ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default

but I don't have a Default folder in any `Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome` path I can find:

Top Level Library:
[image: not in top level Library dir]

myUsername Library:
[image: not in myUsername Library dir]

I'm using OSX Yosemite 10.10.4 and the latest Chrome.  Where else should I look for Chrome User Data?

This other questioner has a different issue than me: [Can't find the Google Chrome User Data Directory in Mac OSX Lion](https://superuser.com/questions/522722/cant-find-the-google-chrome-user-data-directory-in-mac-osx-lion)

Comment: Your second picture for the user Library is looking in the wrong folder. Go into `Application Support` before `Google`.

Comment: @NetherLinks that is the answer!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Chrome stores it's config in a SQLite database.  You can find that database here:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/<profile_name>/databases
```

For example... the system profile is here:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/System Profile/databases
```

Comment: I thought that he said he doesn't have anything in his Chrome folder