# How would I restore data of a Chrome extension only using backup?

Tags: macos, google-chrome-extensions, local-storage

My Mac essentially stopped working, but I have this awesome extension for Google Chrome called [Simple Window Saver](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-window-saver/fpfmklldfnlcblofkhdeoohfppdoejdc), which saves a window with lots of tabs, so I can open it whenever I want to.

I have a backup of my entire Mac, so I know the data is in there somewhere but I don't understand how I can transfer it to a new computer.

I tried copying the extension from Default/Extensions, but that did not seem to work.

Looking at the JS files, it looks like the extension uses local storage to store data. So I am guessing I would need to access that to find my data.

Where would I find this data and what should I look for when transferring it to the new computer? Or if this is not at all correct, where would I find the data from the Chrome extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround I used in the end that got my saved sessions for Simple Window Saver moved to a new system was just brute force:

1. Close all Chrome tabs on both old and new systems (N/A on the old system for you since it's a backup)
2. On the new system, rename the "User Data" folder to something else (so you've got a backup):

   - Windows: C:\Users\micke\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
   - Mac (and I'd assume Linux): ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/User Data (courtesy of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/522732/105147))
3. Copy the "User Data" folder from the old system to the new system
4. Open Chrome on the new system
5. Sign in to Chrome with the same account you used on the old system, and once Simple Window Saver is added everything should be there

I just got a new laptop and had tried the same things you did. Even copying the files that I saw got updated for the extension when I made a new session didn't work, so I quit wasting my time and just copied everything. Not an elegant solution, but it works.