# Migrate data of a Chrome extension from one computer to another

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, migration, data-migration

I'm looking for how to ***migrate data of a Chrome extension*** from one computer to another. I'm not looking for [migrating extension installation](https://superuser.com/q/634648/371227), but extension's stored data.
By **data**, I mean the normal user's data created through out the extension's usage. What I'm asking about is how to migrate this data, not the extension installation itself. Knowing that the data of the extension I'm trying to migrate isn't stored in the extension's folder existing in something like `…\Profile 2\Extensions\eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl`. I'm not asking about migrating all the Chrome user's data, but the data of a single specific extension only.

**— To here**, my question is thoroughly described.

Below are question sections that may be helpful for progressing towards a solution.

---

**My specific use case:**
I have [Tabs Outliner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-outliner/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl?hl=en) Chrome extension. I have data stored on Computer 1. I copied all these files/folders from Computer 1 to Computer 2:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 2\IndexedDB\chrome-extension_eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl_0.indexeddb.leveldb
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 2\Sync Extension Settings\eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 2\IndexedDB\chrome-extension_eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl_0.indexeddb.blob
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 2\databases\chrome-extension_eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl_0
```

After doing this, I expected to find Tabs Outliner Computer 2 having the data that was in Computer 1. Instead, it gives me empty data as if I freshly installed the extension.

---

**Solution Suggestions I tried that didn't work:**

▪ ***[Suggestion #4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27432365/3503851)***: Calling `chrome.storage.local.get(function(result){console.log(result)})` from console on the extension's page.

- It returned just a prototype, not the actual data object.

▪ ***[Suggestion #3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9404841/3503851)***: Using Chrome Developer tools to access the local storage.

- Unfortunately it doesn't provide any feature to export/import the whole data set. It only enables the user to edit cells manually.

▪ ***[Suggestion #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27434046/3503851)***: Using below extensions trying to export Local Storage from Computer 1 then import on Computer 2.

- [Storage Area Explorer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storage-area-explorer/ocfjjjjhkpapocigimmppepjgfdecjkb), problem with it is that the export functionality isn't working, so I can't test it.
- [LocalStorage Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/localstorage-manager/fkhoimdhngkiicbjobkinobjkoefhkap), problem with it is that it doesn't read Local Storage at all.

▪ ***[Suggestion #1](https://superuser.com/a/634658/371227)***: Copying the extension's folder located in `…\Profile 2\Extensions\eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl` from Computer 1 to Computer 2.

- It seems it doesn't contain the extension's data at all because the extension folder's size is very small.
- The solution was suggested by an answer to a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/634648/copy-chrome-extensions-from-one-computer-to-another) that seems duplicate to mine, but it's not, as it asks about installing chrome extension without the Google Web Store using offline files. While I'm asking about extracting the extension's data from one computer then copying it to another.

---

**Seems helpful hints:**
▪ ***Hint #1***: Tabs Outliner has data stored in ***local storage***. I think if these local storage data is accessed from a file or somehow, if we copied it, then the job is done. (Hint inspirer: Suggestions 2 and 3)

▪ ***Hint #2***: Tabs Outliner seems to have data stored in IndexedDB, as well, local storage.

- [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy Chrome extensions from one computer to another](https://superuser.com/questions/634648/copy-chrome-extensions-from-one-computer-to-another)

Comment: @harrymc I don’t think this is a duplicate. My question is about
migrating extension's data, while the question you linked is about
just migrating extension (specifically installing extension silently and offline) without considering the extension's data.

Comment: It is a duplicate if the extension data is kept inside the extension's folder, since you copy the entire folder. Try it and see if that's your case.

Comment: @harrymc The data of the extension isn't kept inside the extension's folder for Tabs Outliner. I've tried to migrate the extension's folder and it just loaded the extension without any data I have on computer 1.

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922964/how-do-i-view-the-storage-of-a-chrome-extension-ive-installed) might help in finding it.

Comment: @harrymc It helped me have a good hint. That Tabs Outliner has its data stored in local storage. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to export the local storage using any of the suggestions in the post.

Comment: Why don't you copy the entire folders of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome` and `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome`?

Comment: @harrymc I want to be extension specific. This will be helpful if I don't have other extensions' data on Computer 2 that I care about keeping there data. With this solution I will lose them by overwriting with all data from Computer 1. I just need to migrate only the data of Tabs Outliner without losing any other extendion's data.

Comment: You might be able to export/import the data with the extension [LocalStorage Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/localstorage-manager/fkhoimdhngkiicbjobkinobjkoefhkap).

Comment: @harrymc [LocalStorage Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/localstorage-manager/fkhoimdhngkiicbjobkinobjkoefhkap) doesn't read the Local Storage at all. I tried refreshing the extension's page many times and reviewed the permissions, also it's not able to read the Local Storage.

Comment: There seems a rather [simple way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9404841/165358) of doing it.

Comment: @harrymc Unfortunately it doesn't provide any feature to export/import the whole data set. It only enables the user to edit cells manually.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: Probable duplicate of [How do you copy chrome extension data from one computer to another?](https://superuser.com/a/1581700) ← link to my (not generally complete) answer there.  It’s a pity that Question is older, because you have done such a great job outlining the problem! ´xD

Answer (score 1):

There are more directories for Chrome extension data in Windows. Organized by *extension_id* it is stored at these paths:

```
C:\Users\[user_name]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Extension Settings\[extension_id]

C:\Users\[user_name]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Sync Extension Settings\[extension_id]

C:\Users\[user_name]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\IndexedDB\chrome-extension_[extension_id]
```

Copying files from/to extension directories may help depending on your extension structure. Not necessarily all three directories are populated/created (again this depends on extension behaviour).

Just inspect these and experiment.

**Do a proper backup beforehand though!**

Answer (score 1):

As per your specific use case, the steps to migrate the 'Tabs Outliner' extension are outlined by the developer [here](https://groups.google.com/g/tabs-outliner-support-group/c/eKubL9Iw230/m/wQXOP1m90NoJ) (I have followed these instructions on a number of occasions, so I know that they work).

As explained in the link, the trick for a successful migration of the data is to first ensure that the extension is removed on the target Chrome. Then copy the data across. Then install the extension on the target Chrome. The extension should then use the migrated data.

This methodology also works for most other extensions, providing you a) know where the extension is storing the data and b) there are no specific customisations that will prevent it from working. Consequently, gaining details on data migration from the developer of the extension is best.

Due to the differing intricacies of data storage between extensions, it is often easier to simply copy the entire Chrome profile to the other computer, thereby preventing any problems.
At the time of writing, I have successfully migrated a Chrome profile to another PC with Google Chrome, but when trying this with the Brave browser (v1.43.89 Chromium: 105.0.5195.102), it reset my settings and removed the extensions. It is possible that if I simply re-installed the extensions again in Brave, that the migrated extension data would then be used, but I didn't try this. So, just because it is possible to do one thing in Google Chrome, it doesn't mean that it is possible to do it in other, similar, browsers. Fortunately, it is possible to individually migrate the extension's specific data in Brave browser, as per this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think [CloneApp](https://github.com/builtbybel/CloneApp) is designed to do just that.
It's a program meant to migrate software from one system to another.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1220728)

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

1. Back up your new system's User Data folder and keep the backup folder someplace safe.
2. [Copy the old system's profile folder](https://superuser.com/a/1238381), or alternatively [copy the entire User Data folder](https://superuser.com/a/1171185).
3. Move the copy of the old folder to somewhere on your new system, *but don't replace the new system's existing folder.*
4. Then run 'diff' to find the differences between the old system's folder and the new system's folder.
5. Copy the different files from the old system's folder into the corresponding folder on the new system.

Then see if it worked. (If it didn't, you can restore the new system's folder from the backup you created in step 1.)

Comment: This solution will not help because I want to copy the data of a single specific extension only (not all extensions).