# Google Chrome has crashed

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, crash

I was using Chrome just nicely until the moment that I was obliged to turn my PC off because of the blue screen. So far, I can't start Google Chrome as it immediately crashes.

I need my history and bookmarks. How can I fix this?

Here are the details:

```
Signature du problème :
  Nom d’événement de problème:  APPCRASH
  Nom de l’application: chrome.exe
  Version de l’application: 37.0.2062.103
  Horodatage de l’application:  54011f26
  Nom du module par défaut: chrome.dll
  Version du module par défaut: 37.0.2062.103
  Horodateur du module par défaut:  54011c47
  Code de l’exception:  80000003
  Décalage de l’exception:  004fbf54
  Version du système:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Identificateur de paramètres régionaux:   1036
  Information supplémentaire n° 1:  0a9e
  Information supplémentaire n° 2:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Information supplémentaire n° 3:  0a9e
  Information supplémentaire n° 4:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Lire notre déclaration de confidentialité en ligne :
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x040c

Si la déclaration de confidentialité en ligne n’est pas disponible, lisez la version hors connexion :
  C:\Windows\system32\fr-FR\erofflps.txt
```

Comment: You should be worried about the blue screen instead of Chrome.

Comment: Have you tried to start Chrome, after you backup your profile, but with a clean profile and to see if it will work?

Answer (score 1):

> **I need my history and bookmarks**

In `C:\Users\Waoula\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` (or equivalent location) are files `Bookmarks` and `History`

- **Bookmarks** is in XML format, you can open it in any text editor (but don't make changes!)
- **History** is in SQLite format. There exist [browsers](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser) for this format.

I haven't tried it but you may be able to copy these files somewhere safe and copy them back after a reinstallation of Chrome (assuming uninstallation doesn't leave them in-place anyway).

> **I can't start Google Chrome as it immediately crashes.**

I would check task manager for a stalled chrome.exe process.

See also [How to open Google Chrome with extensions disabled / turned off?](https://superuser.com/q/254579/52492)