# Fat-fingering Chrome to close unexpectedly?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

A few times recently I believe I have hit an unintentional keystroke / chord which tells Chrome to quit. I don't think it shuts down due to malfunction, and I am able to restart right away and restore tabs, etc.

This occurs when I was trying to type normally into a text field, and I have the impression that I've hit some unidentified key combination that forces an exit.

Whatever it is causes Chrome to quit instantly. I don't usually run multiple windows so I'm not sure if it is truly "quitting" or just "closing" the current window which results in a process termination.

(Something LIKE <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> on Windows, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> - but neither of these in actuality).

*Are there other key combinations which tells Chrome to close?* Maybe I can work out what I am doing wrong.

---

<sub>Note: this is not the same as [Google Chrome quits unexpectedly](https://superuser.com/questions/845365/google-chrome-quits-unexpectedly), which was some sort of error scenario.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

According to [Chrome Support](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> closes current Chrome window
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> closes all Chrome windows (this shortcut was removed in Chrome 70)