# Ad doesn't appear on one website

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to watch videos on a specific website (wakanim.tv) on google chrome.

To watch something for free on that website, you must first watch an ad but the problem is that the ad doesn't appear. There is only a little tab, which says that it's looking for an ad, that appears for less than one second. And the slide bar on the right disappears.
I, of course, disabled AdBlock on that website.

I also tried disabling all my Chrome extensions, my antivirus, all my chrome plugins but flash (I tried with pepper flash and adobe flash) and I also looked at my host file, which hasn't been modified. I can't see where the problem is. (Btw, I'm in dev mode.)

With IE, it works well.

Any help please ?

Comment: Try [starting Chrome with extensions turned off](http://superuser.com/questions/254579/how-to-open-google-chrome-with-extensions-disabled-turned-off).