# Control combined with the "1, 2, 3" digits dont work

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

Since late there's been a weird bug on my computer or keyboard, for the key combination of `control + 1/2/3` don't work anymore. Which I use a lot to switch around in Chrome. This has been really annoying and I have no idea what causes it. 
The thing, it works fine when I use the numpad.

I have a Corsair K70, and the operating system I am using is Windows 10. Does anyone know of this problem or is something wrong with my keyboard?

Sorry, to clarify, I was making an example of it being annoying with Chrome, but it happens everywhere.

Comment: I am neither psychic or a mind reader and I don't like guessing.  What is your operating system? Please [edit] the question and include this essential information.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing the [keyboard driver software](http://www.corsair.com/en-us/support/downloads)?

Comment: My keyboard does not have any drivers from Corsair. Those are only for the RGB versions, thus they do nothing on mine. They are just for controlling colours.

Comment: @Stepepper OK, thanks for clarifying that. Have you made sure that it is not an extension interering with your key presses: [How to open Google Chrome with extensions disabled / turned off?](http://superuser.com/q/254579/272824)

Comment: @AndrewMorton It's not Chrome's fault. It happens in every program that I use.

Comment: @Stepepper Err... the 1, 2 and 3 keys are working anyway, aren't they? (E.g. test in Notepad.) You didn't say.

Comment: Yeah they are, they work just fine. 123. I also typed them in the title os I just assumed. Sorry!

Comment: Open on-screen keyboard (`osk.exe`) and try this key combo with it.

Comment: Didn't work! Just ignored it. I noticed something strange too, when I press the combination in a game the fps lowers about 30% for about a couple seconds and then it goes back up again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have **Nvidia Geforce Experience** installed you may try solution posted on http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-3224159/keys-work-ctrl-pressed.html

> "...I found a solution (at least for myself). I switched off 'SHARE' on my Nvidia GeForce Experience software. For some reason it was causing conflict." -[Rosinho](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-3224159/keys-work-ctrl-pressed.html)

Comment: Wow. That worked. Alright thanks Nvidia, that's something that suddenly broke. I'll award the bounty when I can.

Answer (score 0):

If you can reproduce this problem on demand, then I suggest testing with an additional USB keyboard attached and also some testing with the OSK (On Screen Keyboard). Start > Run > type "osk", to open it.

If the additional keyboard and OSK function properly, then your keyboard is probably defective. if they do not, then probably an OS or driver issue.

Comment: Definitely software, doesn't work with the on screen keyboard and it doesn't work with an additional keyboard. But the combination does also not work in safe mode.